GraalVM native image build fails using EclipseStore: Unable to access java.util.Collections$SetFromMap despite --add-opens
I'm trying to build a native image of my Spring Boot application using GraalVM, but I'm encountering an InaccessibleObjectException related to java.util.Collections$SetFromMap. I've attempted several solutions, but the issue persists.
Environment:

GraalVM Version: 21.0.5 (GraalVM 21.0.5 for Java 21)
Java Version: Java 21
Spring Boot Version: 3.3.5
EclipseStore Version: 2.0.0 (Adding this triggers the issue)
Operating System: Sonoma 14.6.1

Problem Description:
When I add EclipseStore to my Spring Boot application and attempt to build a native image with GraalVM, I encounter the following error related to java.util.Collections$SetFromMap:
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field final java.util.Map java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.m accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @60a7e509
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:183)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.serializer.reflect.XReflect.setAccessible(XReflect.java:110)
    ...

This suggests that the application is attempting to access internal classes via reflection, which is being blocked by the Java module system.
What I've Tried:

Adding --add-opens at Build Time:
In my pom.xml, I included the following build arguments:
<buildArgs>
    <buildArg>--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</buildArg>
</buildArgs>


Adding --add-opens at Runtime:
Updated the build arguments to pass the --add-opens option to the runtime:
<buildArgs>
    <buildArg>-H:AdditionalRuntimeOptions=--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</buildArg>
</buildArgs>


Registering Reflection Hints:
In my RuntimeHints.java, I registered the internal class:
hints.reflection().registerType(
    TypeReference.of("java.util.Collections$SetFromMap"),
    builder -> builder.withMembers(MemberCategory.values())
);


Using Reflection Configuration File:
Created a reflect-config.json file with the necessary configuration.


Despite these attempts, the error remains the same.
Additional Information:

GitHub Repository: LiveNathan/nativeImageTest
Related Discussion: Eclipse Store GitHub Discussion #297

Questions:

Is there a way to properly configure GraalVM and the Java module system to allow reflective access to java.util.Collections$SetFromMap?
Could this issue be due to incompatibilities between EclipseStore and Java 21 or GraalVM 21.0.5?
Are there alternative approaches to resolve this error without relying on internal JDK classes?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, especially from those with experience in GraalVM or working with Java's module system in native images.
Relevant Code:
The breaking change is adding EclipseStore. If I download a new project from Spring Initializer and add my Controller, it can compile to native image and run. As soon as I add EclipseStore, the error occurs when the native image is run. Nothing I have tried above seems to change the outcome.
public class EclipseAccountAdapter {
    private final EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EclipseAccountAdapter.class);
    private final ApplicationContext context;

    public EclipseAccountAdapter(EmbeddedStorageManager storageManager, ApplicationContext context) {
        this.storageManager = storageManager;
        this.context = context;
        initializeRoot();
    }

    private void initializeRoot() {
        if (storageManager.root() == null) {
            log.info("Initializing root.");
            storageManager.setRoot(new DataRoot());
            storageManager.storeRoot();
        }
    }

    @Write
    public int save(Account account, StorerType storerType) {
        getRoot().accounts().add(account);
        store(getRoot().accounts().usernameToAccount(), storerType);
        return getRoot().accounts().all().size();
    }

    @Read
    public List<Account> findAll() {
        return new ArrayList<>(getRoot().accounts().all());
    }

    private DataRoot getRoot() {
        return (DataRoot) storageManager.root();
    }

    private void store(final Object object, StorerType storerType) {
        try {
            switch (storerType) {
                case LAZY: {
                    Storer lazyStorer = storageManager.createLazyStorer();
                    lazyStorer.store(object);
                    lazyStorer.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case EAGER: {
                    Storer eagerStorer = storageManager.createEagerStorer();
                    eagerStorer.store(object);
                    eagerStorer.commit();
                }
                default:
                    storageManager.store(object);
            }
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            onStorageFailure(t);
        }
    }

    private void onStorageFailure(final Throwable t) {
        if (storageManager != null && storageManager.isRunning()) {
            try {
                log.error("Storage error! Shutting down storage...", t);
                SpringApplication.exit(context, () -> 0);
            } catch (final Throwable throwable) {
                log.error(throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
            }
        }
        DataRoot root = getRoot();
        if (root != null) {
            root.clear();
        }
    }
}

pom.xml Snippet:
Here’s a partial pom.xml with only the key dependencies and GraalVM build arguments:
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot and GraalVM dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.store</groupId>
        <artifactId>storage-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
            <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Stack Trace
After compiling the native image with ./mvnw -Pnative -DbuildArgs="-Ob" native:compile -DskipTests and then running it:
2024-10-27T08:01:30.632-05:00  INFO 19610 --- [nativeImageTest] [           main] d.n.nativeImageTest.ServiceConfig        : Initializing EmbeddedStorageManager...
2024-10-27T08:01:30.634-05:00  WARN 19610 --- [nativeImageTest] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'eclipseAccountAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eclipseAccountAdapter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'injectStorageTest': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
2024-10-27T08:01:30.634-05:00  INFO 19610 --- [nativeImageTest] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'eclipseAccountAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eclipseAccountAdapter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'injectStorageTest': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eclipseAccountAdapter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eclipseAccountAdapter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'injectStorageTest': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectStorageTest': Instantiation of supplied bean failed
Caused by: org.eclipse.serializer.exceptions.NoSuchNestedClassRuntimeException: No nested class java.util.Collections$SetFromMap found in class java.util.Collections
    at org.eclipse.serializer.reflect.XReflect.getDeclaredNestedClass(XReflect.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.serializer.persistence.binary.java.util.BinaryHandlerSetFromMap.New(BinaryHandlerSetFromMap.java:39)


Note: I've reviewed similar questions and documentation but haven't found a solution that works. If anyone has faced a similar issue or knows how to address this, your help would be invaluable.

It seems like the stack trace in the discussion you linked is a different exception (it doesn't seem to mention anything about a InaccessibleObjectException. Is that intentional?

Apart from that, does the code work on GraalVM 21 in JIT mode (with the respective --add-opens)?

Would it be possible to create a [mcve] without Spring (and ideally also without the library)?

I was testing that accessing java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.m (using setAccessible() without using Spring/EclipseStore and that worked with --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED and [{"name" : "java.util.Collections$SetFromMap", "fields": [{"name" : "m"}]}] in the reflect-config.json.

"is a different exception"
Yes, the errors have changed as I have tried different ways to solve it.

@dan1st Thanks for your question! I haven’t yet tried running it in JIT mode on GraalVM 21 with the --add-opens flags. I was focused on the native image, but testing in JIT mode could help narrow down where this accessibility issue originates. I’ll give it a try and update soon. Thanks again for the suggestion!

@dan1st Thanks for the suggestion! I ran the .jar file in JIT mode with GraalVM 21 using the --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED argument, and it worked without issues. This confirms that the reflection errors are specific to the native image compilation, I think.

@dan1st "without Spring (and ideally also without the library)?"  I suppose so, but I'm not sure what that would accomplish. I need both Spring Boot and EclipseStore for my project.

Having a minimal reproducer makes it easier to reproduce and try to fix it.

@dan1st Thanks for the guidance! I tried running in JIT mode with --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED, and it worked fine. I then updated my native image config to include --add-opens in buildArgs and added a reflect-config.json with:
{
  "name": "java.util.Collections$SetFromMap",
  "fields": [{ "name": "m", "allowWrite": true }]
}

After recompiling, I’m still hitting the same InaccessibleObjectException for SetFromMap.m.

I made a new example with Spring Boot only and now the error is "release version 23 not supported" so maybe I'll try version 21 instead.
https://github.com/LiveNathan/nativeImageTest

You mentioned the problem being a InaccessibleObjectException with java.util.Collections$SetFromMap. I think this wouldn't happen with Spring Boot only.

Ok, I got the new version without EclipseStore to compile and run as a native image using 21 instead of 23.

Does the exception happen if you are doing that? If so, can you share that reproducer (ideally as part of this question without relying on links)?

I rebuilt the project from scratch, proved that it could compile to native image with only spring boot and run the image. I added EclipseStore, ran the graalvm tracing agent, compiled to native, and ran the image. Exact same error as before.

Thanks for the suggestion, @dan1st . Yes, the exception still occurs when I add EclipseStore to a minimal project and try to build a native image. Yes, I could copy/paste the code, but I'm not sure what to share because I don't understand the problem. I would have to copy in every class. Linking to github seems more efficient than pasting in all of the code. Unless there's a class you recommend that I share?

Ideally, you would be able to reproduce it with a single class (containing the operation causing the issue) and include that, explain how you specify the reflect-config.json (e.g. -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=), the full stack trace as well as the exact dependency and its version. If you need many classes to reproduce it, it isn't a minimal reproducible example. We don't need your project logic, we need to have a minimal way to reproduce and debug the problem.

@dan1st Ah, ok. Thanks. I have updated the question to make it more clear that the error occurs as soon as EclipseStore is added and nothing I've tried seems to change that.

It seems like the class you provided requires Spring and other classes not present here. Please make sure that your example is minimal enough so it fits in your post and can be reproduced solely with the information in your post (without needing to clone the GitHub repository). Spring is everything but minimal (unless the issue only happens with Spring) and the amount of classes in your GitHub repository is also far from minimal.

Hi @dan1st
Thanks for the input. I've updated the question to better follow your suggestions, simplifying the example as much as I can while keeping Spring, since my experience is mostly Spring-based and removing it entirely is challenging at my skill level. I've included what I believe are the essential parts of the code and config.
If you have any solution-focused advice on troubleshooting the specific error, especially around GraalVM or EclipseStore config, it would be incredibly helpful. Thanks for your patience as I work to improve the question.

The issue you are facing doesn't come from EclipseStore but actually from Eclipse serializer (project page) (but also how some Eclipse Store classes are used with Eclipse Serializer).
Actually, there are two types of issues you are facing as you already noticed: Allowing deep reflective access to Collections.SetFromMap#m and providing reflective hints.
Your --add-opens already works
Your attempt 1 should already take care of the issue with reflective access:
<buildArgs>
    <buildArg>--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</buildArg>
</buildArgs>

Using the agent with your tests
For reflective hints, you can use the agent (which you already tried). Since you already have tests, you can just run these tests with -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=/path/to/your/suggested/agent/output.
You can do that by temporarily adding that argument to the maven-surefire-plugin and running mvn test:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- TODO replace the path with the actual path you want -->
        <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=/path/to/your/suggested/agent/output</argLine>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

This should create the directory /path/to/your/suggested/agent/output with a reflect-config.json file that contains everything that's reflectively accessed using tests. You can then copy that file in your project and use that whenever you are building a native executable. Note that you only have to generate that file once (or possibly recreate it if you update that library and run into similar issues), not every time you want to build the executable. You can remove or comment out that part in your pom.xml afterwards (or use a <profile> for it).
Assuming you copied that file to native-image-config/reflect-config.json, you can add -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=native-image-config/reflect-config.json to the native-image arguments:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <buildArgs>
            <buildArg>--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</buildArg>
            <buildArg>-H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=native-image-config/reflect-config.json</buildArg>
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Properly fixing reflective hints
To make the library compatible with native-image, these hints should either be added as part of the library or to the GraalVM reachability metadata repository. To do this, you might want to create an issue in the issue tracker of the project (Eclipse serializer) and ask them to either add it to their JAR or to the reachability metadata repository. It will likely be helpful if you include the reflect-config.json you got from running the agent. However, when doing so, please run the agent on a project using Eclipse serializer and nothing else, especially without Spring (or run the Eclipse serializer tests with the agent and collect its output).
If Eclipse serializer bundles the reflective hints or these are provided in the reachability metadata repository, others should be able to use it without needing to configure everything by themselves.
Cleaning up the reflect-config.json
Since Spring and many other things (which already provide hints) are using reflection, your reflect-config.json also contains a lot of stuff you don't need to specify again. You can try to reduce your reflect-config.json by removing everything that isn't related to Eclipse Store or Eclipse Serializer and also keeping java.util.Collections$SetFromMap. When I did that, the file had only 97 entries left as opposed to 1205 entries before.
In my case, the cleaned up reflect-config.json looks as follows:
[
{
  "name":"java.util.Collections$SetFromMap",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"[Lorg.eclipse.serializer.persistence.binary.types.BinaryField;"
},
{
  "name":"[Lorg.eclipse.serializer.persistence.binary.types.BinaryReferenceTraverser;"
},
{
  "name":"[Lorg.eclipse.serializer.persistence.binary.types.LoadItemsChain$Entry;"
},
{
  "name":"[Lorg.eclipse.serializer.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDefinitionMemberFieldGeneric;"
},
{
  "name":"[Lorg.eclipse.serializer.persistence.types.PersistenceTypeDescription;"
},
{
  "name":"[Lorg.eclipse.store.afs.nio.types.NioReadableFile$Default;"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.BulkList",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.ConstHashEnum",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.ConstHashTable",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.ConstHashTable$Keys"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.ConstHashTable$Values"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.ConstList",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.Empty",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EmptyTable",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EmptyTable$Keys",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EmptyTable$Values",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqBulkList",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqConstHashEnum",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqConstHashTable",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqConstHashTable$Keys"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqConstHashTable$Values"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqHashEnum",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqHashTable",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqHashTable$Keys"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.EqHashTable$Values"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.FixedList",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.HashEnum",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.HashTable",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.HashTable$Keys"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.HashTable$Values"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.LimitList",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.Singleton",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazyArrayList",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"addSegment","parameterTypes":["int","int","java.lang.Object"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazyArrayList$Segment",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"cleanModified","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"getLazy","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"getLazyData","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazyHashMap",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"addSegment","parameterTypes":["int","int","int","java.lang.Object"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazyHashMap$LazyHashMapSegmentEntryList",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazyHashMap$Segment",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"cleanModified","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"getLazy","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"getLazyData","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazyHashSet",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.collections.lazy.LazySegmentUnloader"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.hashing.HashEqualator"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.hashing.XHashing$SingletonIdentityHashEqualator",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.hashing.XHashing$SingletonKeyValueIdentityHashEqualator",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.hashing.XHashing$SingletonValueHashEqualator",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "unsafeAllocated":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.memory.sun.JdkInternals$ObjectHeaderSizeDummy",
  "allDeclaredFields":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.monitoring.LazyReferenceManagerMonitor",
  "queryAllPublicConstructors":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.monitoring.LazyReferenceManagerMonitorMBean",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.monitoring.MonitorDescription",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"value","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.persistence.binary.java.net.BinaryHandlerInetSocketAddress",
  "allDeclaredFields":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.persistence.types.PersistenceRootReference$Default",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.persistence.types.PersistenceRoots$Default",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.reference.ControlledLazyReference$Default",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Object","long","org.eclipse.serializer.reference.ObjectSwizzling"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.reference.Lazy$Default",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Object","long","org.eclipse.serializer.reference.ObjectSwizzling"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.reflect.ClassLoaderProvider",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.serializer.util.Substituter$Default",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.DefaultEclipseStoreConfiguration",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"defaultEclipseStoreProperties","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.DefaultEclipseStoreConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredConstructors":true,
  "fields":[{"name":"CGLIB$FACTORY_DATA"}],
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"CGLIB$SET_STATIC_CALLBACKS","parameterTypes":["org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback[]"] }, {"name":"CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS","parameterTypes":["org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback[]"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.DefaultEclipseStoreConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$0",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Class"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.DefaultEclipseStoreConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Class"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.EclipseStoreSpringBoot",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"classLoaderProvider","parameterTypes":["org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext"] }, {"name":"eclipseStoreConfigConverter","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"embeddedStorageFoundationFactory","parameterTypes":["org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.converter.EclipseStoreConfigConverter","org.eclipse.serializer.reflect.ClassLoaderProvider"] }, {"name":"embeddedStorageManagerFactory","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.EclipseStoreSpringBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$0",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredConstructors":true,
  "fields":[{"name":"CGLIB$FACTORY_DATA"}],
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"CGLIB$SET_STATIC_CALLBACKS","parameterTypes":["org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback[]"] }, {"name":"CGLIB$SET_THREAD_CALLBACKS","parameterTypes":["org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Callback[]"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.EclipseStoreSpringBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$0",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Class"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.EclipseStoreSpringBoot$$SpringCGLIB$$FastClass$$1",
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":["java.lang.Class"] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.concurrent.Read",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.concurrent.Write",
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.ConfigurationPair"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.EclipseStoreProperties",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"<init>","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"close","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"shutdown","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.StorageFilesystem"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.aws.AbstractAwsProperties"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.aws.Aws"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.azure.Azure"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.oraclecloud.Oraclecloud"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.sql.AbstractSqlConfiguration"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.configuration.sql.Sql"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.converter.EclipseStoreConfigConverter",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"close","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"shutdown","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.factories.EmbeddedStorageFoundationFactory",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"close","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"shutdown","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.factories.EmbeddedStorageManagerFactory",
  "allDeclaredFields":true,
  "queryAllDeclaredMethods":true,
  "methods":[{"name":"close","parameterTypes":[] }, {"name":"shutdown","parameterTypes":[] }]
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.integrations.spring.boot.types.suppliers.EmbeddedStorageFoundationSupplier"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.embedded.configuration.types.EmbeddedStorageConfigurationBuilder"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.embedded.types.EmbeddedStorageFoundation"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.embedded.types.EmbeddedStorageManager"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.embedded.types.EmbeddedStorageManager$Default"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.EntityCacheMonitor",
  "queryAllPublicConstructors":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.EntityCacheMonitorMBean",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.EntityCacheSummaryMonitor",
  "queryAllPublicConstructors":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.EntityCacheSummaryMonitorMBean",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.ObjectRegistryMonitor",
  "queryAllPublicConstructors":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.ObjectRegistryMonitorMBean",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageChannelHousekeepingMonitor",
  "queryAllPublicConstructors":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageChannelHousekeepingMonitorMBean",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageManagerMonitor",
  "queryAllPublicConstructors":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageManagerMonitor$ChannelStatistics",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageManagerMonitor$FileStatistics",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageManagerMonitor$StorageStatistics",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.monitoring.StorageManagerMonitorMXBean",
  "queryAllPublicMethods":true
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.types.StorageStructureValidator$Default"
},
{
  "name":"org.eclipse.store.storage.types.StorageSystem$Default"
}
]


Thank you, Dan! I appreciate your insights, especially regarding Eclipse Serializer's reflection access limitations. I’ve marked your answer as accepted since it clarified the next steps and helped me identify this as a compatibility issue rather than a setup error on my part. I’ve now opened a GitHub issue with Eclipse Serializer here to address this. Your guidance was invaluable in helping me move forward—thank you again!
